# EF Core multiple datasets

Tags: entity-framework

I am new to EF and want to return multiple datasets (like we do in stored procedures) in one database trip. I have 3 dropdowns to populate on my form plus the main page fields (which would be another dataset)

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: With asynchronous queries you can get three "datasets" almost simultaneously (would take time of longest dataset)

Comment: If you practising "database programming"(keeping business logic in database stored procedures, views, triggers etc) - EF and your application will probably have "big fight" ;)

Comment: i do not want to split my business logic in 2 places and that's why I am looking to answers to get the 3 resultsets (like stored procedures can return multiple resultsets) in 1 database trip not multiple queries for each dataset which will need 1 trip to database for each dataset which are not related (or no FK at the moment)

Comment: 3 asynchronous trips to database will be quicker than 1 trip for 3 queries.

Comment: @Fabio are you sure about that? is also the db occupation lower?

Answer (score 0):

in this MSDN [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/designer/advanced/multiple-result-sets) sample you can find the full solution

```
using (var db = new BloggingContext())
    {
        // If using Code First we need to make sure the model is built before we open the connection
        // This isn't required for models created with the EF Designer
        db.Database.Initialize(force: false);

        // Create a SQL command to execute the sproc
        var cmd = db.Database.Connection.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "[dbo].[GetAllBlogsAndPosts]";

        try
        {

            db.Database.Connection.Open();
            // Run the sproc
            var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            // Read Blogs from the first result set
            var blogs = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db)
                .ObjectContext
                .Translate<Blog>(reader, "Blogs", MergeOption.AppendOnly);   


            foreach (var item in blogs)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
            }        

            // Move to second result set and read Posts
            reader.NextResult();
            var posts = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db)
                .ObjectContext
                .Translate<Post>(reader, "Posts", MergeOption.AppendOnly);


            foreach (var item in posts)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Title);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            db.Database.Connection.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks but this is calling stored procedure for resultset, which I don't want. Because, I want to keep my business logic in code and database is for storing data.